# How to modify a ListView layout into a ListFragment layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

I am using ***TableFixHeaders*** (https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders) - an Android widget library to display tables with headers.
The default **table.xml** layout for this custom table activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.inqbarna.tablefixheaders.TableFixHeaders 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I would like to modify it to be used as a fragment layout, similar to the following example **fragment_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="com.example.fragment.FragmentLayout$S_ListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The code used to populate the custom table list is as follows:

```
public static class S_ListFragment extends ListFragment {   
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Populate list with S_Adpater           
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.table);       

    FragmentLayout outer = new FragmentLayout();                    
    TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableAdapter tableAdapter = outer.new S_Adapter(getActivity());
    tableFixHeaders.setAdapter(tableAdapter);
```

Because I am calling setContentView using the default table.xml layout, I cannot get it to work as a fragment.
 The reference to ***com.inqbarna.tablefixheaders.TableFixHeaders*** inside the **table.xml** is important for the table adapter to work.
I would like to ask for help on how to modify the above **table.xml** layout to change it into the required fragment layout.

**Edited code following suggestions from Luksprog:**

```
public class S_List extends Activity {       
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);    
    }


public static class S_ListFragment extends Fragment {   
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
    private TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders;
    private ETableAdapter tableAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle args) {   
        // set table.xml as the layout for the fragment's view
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, container, false);
        tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders) content.findViewById(R.id.table);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);       

        SAdapter outer = new SAdapter();                    
        tableAdapter = outer.new SListAdapter(getActivity());
        tableFixHeaders.setAdapter(tableAdapter);

        // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
        // fragment directly in the containing UI.
        View eventsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.events);
        mDualPane = eventsFrame != null && eventsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }

        if (mDualPane) {
            // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
            showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
        }
    }
```

**Partial code for ETableAdapter:**

```
import com.inqbarna.tablefixheaders.adapters.BaseTableAdapter;

/**
 * This class implements the main functionalities of the TableAdapter
 * @author Brais Gabín
 */
public abstract class ETableAdapter extends BaseTableAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     *            The current context.
     */
    public ETableAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the context associated with this array adapter. The context is
     * used to create views from the resource passed to the constructor.
     * 
     * @return The Context associated with this adapter.
     */
    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * Quick access to the LayoutInflater instance that this Adapter retrieved
     * from its Context.
     * 
     * @return The shared LayoutInflater.
     */
    public LayoutInflater getInflater() {
        return inflater;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int row, final int column, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (converView == null) {
            converView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResource(row, column), parent, false);  
        }
        setText(converView, getCellString(row, column));
        converView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        //....
            }       
        return converView;
       }
    }



    /**
     * Sets the text to the view.
     * 
     * @param view
     * @param text
     */
    private void setText(View view, String text) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(text);
    }

    /**
     * @param row
     *            the title of the row of this header. If the column is -1
     *            returns the title of the row header.
     * @param column
     *            the title of the column of this header. If the column is -1
     *            returns the title of the column header.
     * @return the string for the cell [row, column]
     */
    public abstract String getCellString(int row, int column);

    public abstract int getLayoutResource(int row, int column);

    public abstract int getColOrder(int column);

    public abstract void setColOrder(int column, int newOrder);

    public abstract void setHeaderId(int column);

    public abstract int getHeaderId(int column);    
}
```

Comment: `TableFixHeaders` is not a `ListView` ... use normal `Fragment` instead `ListFragment` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the `S_ListFragment` is not making any sense.

> I would like to modify it to be used as a fragment layout

Set the content view of the `Activity` to the second layout you posted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="com.example.fragment.FragmentLayout$S_ListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in the `S_ListFragment`'`onCreateView()` method use the `table.xml` layout as the `Fragment`'s view:

```
// You can't extend ListFragment unless the view for that fragment contains a 
// ListView(and with a special id). If the content of your fragment it's just 
// the table.xml layout then you can't extend ListFragment as TableFixHeaders is 
// not a ListView(as Selvin pointed out in his comment)
public static class S_ListFragment extends Fragment {   

    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
    private TableFixHeaders tableFixHeaders;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundler args)   
        // set table.xml as the layout for the fragment's view
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, container, false);
        tableFixHeaders = (TableFixHeaders) content.findViewById(R.id.table);
        return content;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       FragmentLayout outer = new FragmentLayout();                    
       TableAdapter tableAdapter = outer.new S_Adapter(getActivity());
       tableFixHeaders.setAdapter(tableAdapter);
    //...
```

There isn't much sense in re-setting the content view of an `Activity` from a `Fragment` as you basically replace the layout of the `Activity`(containing the fragment from which you do this) with another layout. Also I don't know what `FragmentLayout` is but see if you can't detach the `TableAdapter` class from it so you don't require the outher reference when creating adapters.

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful and I have managed to get the code working as per your suggestions. Thank you! Most appreciated.
I have also detached the ETableAdapter and the SAdapter, which contains the SListAdapter method, however the code still appears to require the outer reference to the SAdapter (see edited code above). Would you be able to suggest how to overcome this outer requirement. Thanks.

Comment: @MarioS First I don't know how `SAdapter` looks like, by detaching I was referring to removing the need for the outer reference by making `ETableAdapter` a static class or by moving it to it's own java file. If you can just move it without needing to refactor the  code otherwise leave it this way.

Comment: I have enclosed the partial code for `ETableAdpater` above. It is in its own java file. Also, the `S_Adapter` is now in its own java file. It is a public class which extends Activity. Inside `S_Adapter` class is the public class `SListAdapter`, which extends `ETableAdapter`. I am not sure if these adapter classes can be made static, as they work with the `TableFixHeaders` external library, which I cannot alter. If you can see a better way of linking to those adapters, I would appreciate your valuable comments.

Comment: @MarioS Your code is confusing as you describe it. The idea was to not have to instantiate `SAdapter`(above you speak of `S_Adapter`) to create an instance of `SListAdapter`. Try to make the `SListAdapter` class as static **if you can**, so you remove the dependency to the `SAdapter` class when creating instances.